# Passing byte array data from C++ to Haxe

Tags: haxe, openfl, cffi

We are trying to pass a raw data from C++ to Haxe, but we had a lot of trebles.

We tried this solution http://community.openfl.org/t/passing-bytes-from-c-to-haxe/8046/2 but was not working for us.

C++

```
void Clazz::func(unsigned char *data, int length)
{
    XXX_ENTER_HAXE();
    val_call1(m_callback->get(), alloc_array(length));
    XXX_EXIT_HAXE();
}
```

Haxe

```
function func(result:ByteArray) : Void {
    //Do the callback
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have just learn how haxe passively receive bytes from C++

### C++:

```
int len = 10;
unsigned char buf[len];
buf[0] = 12;

::Helper_obj* helper = new ::Helper_obj();
printf("Haxe result:%d\n", helper->processBytes(&buf, len));
```

### Haxe:

```
class Helper{
  public function new(){}
  public function processBytes(raw:cpp.Pointer<cpp.Uint8>, len:Int):Int{
    var array<cpp.Uint8> = cpp.NativeArray.toUnmanagedArray(raw, len);
    var bytes:Bytes = Bytes.ofData(array);
    return bytes.get(0);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Haxe result:12
```